# take a screenshot of desktop in Lua

Tags: lua

I want to take a screen shot of the linux desktop on two monitors.

Based on searches, I wrote a simpple code to have an screenshot as:

```
require "display"
local image = display.captureScreen()
display.save( image, { filename="image.png", isFullResolution=true } )
```

but it does not work and gives this error:

```
 /home/a/torch/install/bin/luajit: screenshot.lua:2: attempt to index global 'display' (a nil value)
```

stack traceback:
    screenshot.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...a/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00405d50

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the first line with `local display = require "display"`, as most of the modules return the value to use instead of polluting the "global" table.